# Set Item per page in views

Tags: drupal-7, view

is there a way to set different number of items to display in views that has ajax pager? For example on first load, you have 10 items, after you click loadmore to load another list, you can get 15 items instead.

Thank you for your wisdom!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[views show more](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_show_more) has this functionality.